# is Eclipse Photon IDE is not for Java EE development?

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee

is Eclipse Photon IDE is not for Java EE development ? because on Help --> About Eclipse IDE -- it say Eclipse IDE for committers.

[image]

Comment: My _guess_ would be that this particular Eclipse download came with the necessary plugins to do development _on Eclipse itself_.

Comment: There are lots of different Eclipse packages specialised for different things. Note that Eclipse Photon is now quite old, current releases can be downloaded from https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/ Eclipse 2020-09 is due for release this week.

Comment: You mean this is not for Java web development or Java EE development.

Comment: That particular package was intended for Eclipse developers, it may not have all the plug-ins for Java EE development (but they can be added). Look  at the package download site https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/ for descriptions of what they are for

Comment: Not sure why this question has attracted so many down and close votes. It seems a reasonable question to ask - the wide choice of Eclipse downloads can be a bit confusing for a beginner. The reason given for the close votes is plain wrong - the question isn't asking for a software recommendation.

Answer (score 2):

*Photon* was a *version* of Eclipse while the "Eclipse IDE for Eclipse Committers" is a pre-assembled *package*. Photon as a version is outdated, and that is also the wrong *package* for supporting Java EE development *out of the box*. You can always add those abilities to an existing package.

The up to date **Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers** can be found at https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2020-06/r/eclipse-ide-enterprise-java-developers . A newer version is will be out 2 days from now.